# Definition of orientation on manifolds and global continuous frame

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition, smooth-manifolds, orientation

In Tu and Lee books on smooth manifolds the definition of orientation on a manifolds $M$ is given by

> We first assign a **pointwise orientation** : for every $p \in M$ we choose a class of oriented basis of $T_pM$.
> Next we say that this pointwise orientation is **continuous** if for every $p \in M$ there is a local frame on neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ that is positively oriented at each point of $U$.
> So an **orientation** of $M$ is a **continuous pointwise orientation**.

My question is why don't we use a global frame on $M$ to define orientation ? Is there example of manifolds that doesn't admit global frame but are orientable ? Is there a like with parallelizable manifolds ?

Comment: Do you know the Hairy Ball theorem?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No but now yes ;) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't define an orientation in terms of a global frame simply because, like you speculate, the orientability of a manifold does not imply the existence of a global frame thereon.

For example, all spheres are orientable, but Bott–Milnor (and, independently, Hirzebruch–Kervaire) showed that the only spheres that admit a global frame, are $S^0, S^1, S^3$, and $S^7$; see Corollary 2 of [Bott–Milnor's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1958-64-03/S0002-9904-1958-10166-4/S0002-9904-1958-10166-4.pdf).

A related, easier result is the Hairy Ball Theorem, which says that any even-dimensional sphere $S^{2 n}$, doesn't even admit a single nonvanishing (global) vector field, and so a fortiori (for $n > 0$) $S^{2 n}$ admits no global frame.

All that said, a global frame on a manifold does *determine* an orientation, namely the (unique) orientation for which that frame is positive. So, for example, a nonorientable manifold admits no global frame.